# Auto generate English subtitles from video file

Tags: 18.04, video, subtitle

Is there any good tool which we can use to generate subtitles in English from a video file ? I have a couple of TV shows which would be good if there is a subtitle. I am not looking for a 100 % accurate solution ( I don't mind if it is ) but something that is not very bad is acceptable. The audio is English and mostly US accent.

Thanks.